# Angular How to highlight text when the condition is met

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working on test application that prompts the user to select radio type values from each question, then check if the selected answers are the same as a correct answers from JSON file.

I used `if-else` to check the condition and need to highlight the answers in green or red when the condition is met. Any help would be appreciated!

Angular:

```
  selectedAnswers:Array<string>=[];

  getSelectedValues(){
    this.allQuestions.forEach(()=>{
      this.selectedAnswers = Object.values(this.myForm.value);
    })
    console.log(this.selectedAnswers);

    for(var i=0; i<this.allQuestions.length; i++){
      let highlight = this.selectedAnswers[i];
      console.log(highlight);   //returns an element

      if(highlight === this.allQuestions[i].correctAns){
        if(this.selectedAnswers === null){
        }
        else{
          console.log("highlight Correct Answer text in green")
        }
      }
      else{
        if(this.selectedAnswers === null){
        }
        else{
          console.log("highlight Wrong answer text in red")
          console.log("highlight Correct Answer text in green")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2>Angular Exam using Model Driven Form</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="getSelectedValues()">
        <div *ngFor="let q of allQuestions; let i = index">
            <p>{{i + 1}}. {{q.question}}</p>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans1}}><span id="{{q.ans1}}">{{q.ans1}}</span> <br>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans2}}><span id="{{q.ans2}}">{{q.ans2}}</span> <br>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans3}}><span id="{{q.ans3}}">{{q.ans3}}</span> <br>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans4}}><span id="{{q.ans4}}">{{q.ans4}}</span> <br>
        </div><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you declare the form with right formcontrols ?
I think you might want to try using formArray or seperate variables for each answers.

Comment: @NikhilVS When I console.log I get the outputs correct. I just need to highlight the test when if-else condition is met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create another loop in your component. You already have loop in your template. You can use `ngClass` like this:

First create `highlight` and `incorrect` class in your `CSS` file like this.

```
   .highlight{
      background-color:  green;
    }
    .incorrect{
      background-color: red;
    }
```

Then use it in your template:

```
[ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns === q.ans1, 'incorrect':btn1.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans1 }"
```

Note that you need to know which radio is checked, so you can use template reference variable: `#btn2`

```
<input type="radio" #btn2  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans2}}>
```

You HTML would be look like this:

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="getSelectedValues()">
      <div *ngFor="let q of allQuestions; let i = index">
          <p>{{i + 1}}. {{q.question}}</p>
          <input type="radio" #btn1  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans1}}>
          <span id="{{q.ans1}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns === q.ans1, 'incorrect':btn1.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans1 }">{{q.ans1}}</span> <br>

          <input type="radio" #btn2  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans2}}>
          <span id="{{q.ans2}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] &&  q.correctAns  === q.ans2, 'incorrect':btn2.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns !== q.ans2 }">{{q.ans2}}</span> <br>

          <input type="radio" #btn3 formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans3}}>
          <span id="{{q.ans3}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] &&  q.correctAns  === q.ans3, 'incorrect':btn3.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans3 }">{{q.ans3}}</span> <br>

          <input type="radio" #btn4  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans4}}>
          <span [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  === q.ans4, 'incorrect':btn4.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans4 }" id="{{q.ans4}}">{{q.ans4}}</span> <br>
      </div><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
  </form>
```

Here is working sample that I created for you: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-f1wz8x?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srhiwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmdf-exam%2Fmdf-exam.component.ts) It still does not highlight the correct & wrong answers. I don't know why my stackblitz is not loading but it loads on my VSC. @AlirezaAhmadi

Comment: @JasonSeo that's happen because you forgot change the `my-appt` in  `index.html`. Just Open `index.html` and change the `my-app` to `app-root`. Here is working version of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xxhegt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you :)

Comment: In addition to that, I'm trying to add result feature that shows the number of correctAns/totalQuestions with passing grade or fail. How would that be done? For example, https://ibb.co/X5P7VXj

Comment: @JasonSeo It's hard to answer in comment can you ask another question. then I am going to answer it with comprehensive explanation

Comment: just created one here, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917802/angular-calculating-correct-answers-and-display-in-result-after-multiple-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If your form group works perfectly. then I think below code will work

Add this pipe and *register it in your module*

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight'
})
export class HeightlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(selectedAnswer: any, answer: string, correctAns: string, isSubmitted: boolean) {
    if (!isSubmitted || !selectedAnswer) { return 'balck'; }
    if (selectedAnswer === answer) {
      return selectedAnswer === correctAns ? 'green' : 'red';
    } else {
      return 'black'
    }
  }
}
```

your component html

```html
<div>
    <h2>Angular Exam using Model Driven Form</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="isSubmitted = true">
        <div *ngFor="let q of allQuestions; let i = index">
            <p>{{i + 1}}. {{q.question}}</p>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans1}}>
            <span [style.color]="myForm.get(q.question).value | highlight: q.ans1: q.correctAns : isSubmitted" id="{{q.ans1}}">{{q.ans1}}</span> <br>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans2}}>
            <span [style.color]="myForm.get(q.question).value | highlight: q.ans2: q.correctAns : isSubmitted" id="{{q.ans2}}">{{q.ans2}}</span> <br>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans3}}>
            <span [style.color]="myForm.get(q.question).value | highlight: q.ans3: q.correctAns : isSubmitted" id="{{q.ans3}}">{{q.ans3}}</span> <br>
            <input type="radio" formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans4}}>
            <span [style.color]="myForm.get(q.question).value | highlight: q.ans4: q.correctAns : isSubmitted" id="{{q.ans4}}">{{q.ans4}}</span> <br>
        </div><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
    </form>
</div>
```

your component ts

```
  isSubmitted = false;
```

Once you submitted, you can use isSubmitted to disable your radio buttons if you want.