# Angular Calculating correct answers and display in result after multiple answers are submitted in test app

Tags: html, angular, typescript

After user submitted multiple answer choices using the radio button. How can I implement result feature including the number of `correctAns/totalQuestions` with passing grade or fail? For example,

[image]

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2>Angular Exam using Model Driven Form</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="getSelectedValues()">
        <div *ngFor="let q of allQuestions; let i = index">
            <p>{{i + 1}}. {{q.question}}</p>
            <input type="radio" #btn1  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans1}}>
            <span id="{{q.ans1}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  === q.ans1, 'incorrect':btn1.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans1 }">{{q.ans1}}</span> <br>
  
            <input type="radio" #btn2  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans2}}>
            <span id="{{q.ans2}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  === q.ans2, 'incorrect':btn2.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans2 }">{{q.ans2}}</span> <br>
  
            <input type="radio" #btn3 formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans3}}>
            <span id="{{q.ans3}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  === q.ans3, 'incorrect':btn3.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans3 }">{{q.ans3}}</span> <br>
  
            <input type="radio" #btn4  formControlName={{q.question}} value={{q.ans4}}>
            <span id="{{q.ans4}}" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  === q.ans4, 'incorrect':btn4.checked && selectedAnswers[i] && q.correctAns  !== q.ans4 }">{{q.ans4}}</span> <br>
        </div><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">
    </form>
  </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
  selectedAnswers:Array<string>=[];
  getSelectedValues(){
    this.allQuestions.forEach(()=>{
      this.selectedAnswers = (<any>Object).values(this.myForm.value);
    })
    console.log(this.selectedAnswers);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedAnswers.length; i++) {
      if(this.selectedAnswers[i] == this.allQuestions[i].correctAns)
      
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just `if selectedAnswer == rightAnswer` and if true increment a counter by a certain value and then add a paragraph with `Res: {counter}/10: {pass}`. Pass is `"Pass!"` when `counter > minimumPoints`, else is `Fail!`. I don't know Angular at all, but I worked with React in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select correct answer, so n your `getSelectedValues` method do like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedAnswers.length; i++) {
      if(this.selectedAnswers[i] == this.allQuestions[i].correctAns)
      this.correctAnswers.push(this.selectedAnswers[i]);
}
```

And in in your template:

```
<p *ngIf="correctAnswers"> Result: {{correctAnswers.length}} / {{allQuestions.length}}
    <span style="color:green" *ngIf="correctAnswers.length > 5"> passed </span>
    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="correctAnswers.length <= 5"> failed </span>
</p>
```

Here is working sample: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ac6ouy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmdf-exam%2Fmdf-exam.component.html)

Comment: @JasonSeo Note that you can change the constant value of passing and failure criteria (here is greater than  `5` correct answer ). I mean you can change the number like: `<span style="color:green" *ngIf="correctAnswers.length > 6"> passed </span>`